# ARC Welder app showing blank page on startup

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-14.04, google-chrome-arc

I am using Google Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) in Ubuntu 14.04.1.
I recently installed ARC Welder extension from chrome web store.
when i opened it, it shows blank window..

i tried to install apk files using drag and drop method..
but it's also failed..

now how to install android apps using ARC Welder?

Comment: It's probably broken, then. You can look at debug messages at `chrome://extensions/` in Developer Mode and `chrome://inspect/#apps`, and see if there are any errors to report to Google. It's still in Developer Preview, after all.

Comment: chrome://inspect/#apps -it shows nothing , but chrome://extensions/ shows "There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'minimum_chrome_version' is only allowed for extensions, hosted apps, legacy packaged apps, and packaged apps, but this is a shared module.
Unrecognized manifest key 'arc_build_tag'." under ARChon Custom Runtime 1.2 - x86_64

Comment: From there you can open the Dev Tools view for the open ARC welder window (that you say is blank). There are probably errors in there.

Comment: how can i open dev tools view for the open ARC welder window ..?

Comment: In any case, Google is wrong to funnel those questions here. We (non-Google developers) can't really help - what kind of answer do you expect? [File a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) instead. I don't think this question should remain here.

Comment: no friend , i'm not saying Google developers are here.. but many programmer are here to solve this kind problems ,so that only i posted this question for help here.. so don't take me wrong friend..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing and shivaraj's comment mentioning 'ARChon Custom Runtime' gave me a tip. I'd forgotten I'd installed this so I completely removed it from Chrome, re-installed ARC Welder and now it loads without issue.

Comment: your answer looks confusing me...
Its not clear...
friend can please explain your answer clearly ...

Thanks for your response...

Comment: Some time ago I installed the ARChon Custom Runtime (from here: [ARChon Runtime for Chrome](http://archon-runtime.github.io/)) in an attempt to get android apps working on Windows like the ARC welder does. I assumed you had too. I had to uninstall that from chrome to get ARC Welder working. Any clearer?

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this on MAC OSX:

1. Remove ARC from the chrome: `chrome://extensions`
2. Open terminal, run this: `open ~/Applications/Chrome\ Apps.localized/`
3. Remove from this folder any app that you installed before to ARC Welder.
4. Re-add the extension to your chrome from this link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn